# catkin_make with postgreSQL link pqxx?

Tags: catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

how do i link pqxx to catkin_make?

according to pqxx documentation, i have to add -lpxx -lpq to cmake_args, i added it via --cmake-args "-lpqxx -lpq"

i have undefined references errors when compiling with catkin_make

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286339/catkin_make-with-postgresql-link-pqxx??/) by [ogensyts](https://answers.ros.org/users/33826/ogensyts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hwliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/112654/hwliu/) on 2022-08-03**:
Have you solved this problem? I meet the same question ,can you tell me how the solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin == CMake in this case (ie: when linking libraries).

You have to add your libraries to the appropriate `target_link_libraries(..)` statement. Not to your `catkin_make` invocation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ogensyts](https://answers.ros.org/users/33826/ogensyts/) on 2018-03-23**:
I have put this and it still dosent work : `target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PQXX_LIBRARY} ${POSTGRES_LIBRARIES} ${PQXX_HEADER_PATH} ${POSTGRES_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})`